# Does div with certain content exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a container div called `#container` which has a bunch of `.inside` divs in it, how would I go about checking whether a certain `.inside` div with a specified content (just a string of English text) exists or not? I'm doing this to prevent duplicates in a notification system I'm setting up for a website. I don't need the actual text - just whether it exists. Also, being able to modify the content of the `.inside` div if it's found would be good, so I can increment and show the number of times that message has occurred (grouping, if you like).

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check existence**

```
$("#container .inside:contains('old text')").size() > 0
```

**To modify the text**

```
$("#container .inside:contains('old text')").text('new text');
```

Comment: @melhosseniny - I don't think that you need to check for the size or length here because if it returns empty there will be no text to change.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`contains-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), then the [`length`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to see how many were found.

```
var some_string = "test";

var els_with_string = $('#container .inside:contains(' +  some_string + ')');

  // use .length to check to see if there was at least one
if( els_with_string.length ) {
    alert( "at least one already exists" );
}
```

From the docs:

> **Description:** Select all elements that contain the specified text.
>
> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as bare words or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.

---

With respect to modifying the content if found, it would depend on what sort of modification you want to do. I don't know exactly what you mean by grouping.

---

**EDIT:** With respect to your comment, you could accomplish what you need like this:

```
var error = "ERROR:SomeError ";
var el_with_error = $('#container .inside:contains(' + error + ')');

if (el_with_error.length) {
    var text = el_with_error.text();
    if (/\(\d+\)/.test(text)) {
        var new_text = text.replace(/\((\d+)\)/, function(s, g1) {
            g1++;
            return "(" + g1 + ")";
        });
        el_with_error.text(new_text);
    } else {
        el_with_error.text(text + " (2)");
    }
} else {
    $('#container').append('<div class="inside">' + error + '</div>');
}
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ScZbV/

We could get by without the regular expression if you were able to wrap the grouping quantity in a `<span>` element.

```
var error = "ERROR:SomeError ";
var el_with_error = $('#container .inside:contains(' + error + ')');

if (el_with_error.length) {
    var span = el_with_error.find('span');
    if (span.length) {
        var num = +span.text();
        span.text( ++num );
    } else {
        el_with_error.append(" (<span>2</span>)");
    }
} else {
    $('#container').append('<div class="inside">' + error + '</div>');
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ScZbV/1/

Comment: Say a user clicks the same button twice, and the same error is generated. Instead of appending another error to the list, I'd like to just add a little `(2)` in the existing error and flash the background as an attention grabber. That's what I mean by grouping. Sorry I wasn't clear enough!

Comment: @JamWaffles: I'll update with a more precise solution in a minute.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort patrick :-) I really appreciate it. I got it working on my own, without having to use regex thankfully (I don't understand it enough). I'd upvote you more than once, but SO isn't nice enough!

Answer (score 2):

I like using selectors (others have used `.filter`, which is equally an option).

```
$(".inside:contains('waldo')").css({color: 'red'});
```

This is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different way of looking at it...

Apply a class name for each "type" of notification. So your notification markup looks like:

```
<div class="inside error">Error</div>
```

Then inside of looking for a string inside these divs, use these new class names to your advantage and make use of .find(). If jQuery returns an object then its exists, so do something with it. But if it returns nothing then add it.

Example: http://jsbin.com/imexi4

Comment: Thanks amustill, however this isn't quite the behaviour I'm looking for as there can be multiple notifications of the same type, however no _duplicate_ notifications can exist.